# How to get number of job created by the Linux "at" command

Tags: linux, bash, at-job

I know I can create and remove scheduled jobs using the Linux `at` and `atrm` commands. Is there a way to get the number of a job at the time `at` is executed?

`atrm` needs the job number to remove it. I can think of workarounds like using unique queue names when inserting jobs, then fetching the list of jobs with `atq`, parsing the lines and finding the one I need so finally the job number can be passed to `atrm`. But this seems overly complicated.

What I'm looking for is to persist the job number at the time of creation so if I need to remove it, I already have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least my version of `at` prints the created job number when adding the job, it should be fairly trivial to extract it from there:

```sh
$ echo /bin/true | at now + 1hour
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 5 at Fri Jun  7 14:13:00 2013
$ echo /bin/true | at now + 1hour 2>&1 | tail -1 | cut -f2 -d" "
6
```